# Substract a DateInterval from another DateInterval

Tags: php, date, dateinterval

```
$date1 = new DateInterval('PT100S'); //100 seconds
$date2 = new DateInterval('PT20S');  //20 seconds
```

How to make `$date1 - $date2`? I've searched on google for hours.

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Comment: Yes, I googled for hours...

Comment: Before you try to accept all answers. You can't. You have to decide for one. Just choose the one, which you think helped you the most and solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to get the number of seconds, then do the subtraction.

```
echo $date1->format('%s') - $date2->format('%s');
```

<sub>Is this what you wanted?</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I simply get the [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) from the defined `$keys`, with both DateInterval objects. So that I then can loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and subtract  the values. With the calculated values I create a new [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) object, which I then return.

```
<?php

    $date1 = new DateInterval('PT100S');
    $date2 = new DateInterval('PT20S'); 

    function subtractDateIntervals($intervalOne, $intervalTwo) {
        $keys = ["y", "m", "d", "h", "i", "s"];

        $intervalArrayOne = array_intersect_key((array)$intervalOne, array_flip($keys));
        $intervalArrayTwo = array_intersect_key((array)$intervalTwo, array_flip($keys));

        $result = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
            return abs($v1 - $v2);
        }, $intervalArrayOne, $intervalArrayTwo);

        return new DateInterval(vsprintf("P%dY%dM%dDT%dH%dM%dS", $result));


    }       

    var_dump(subtractDateIntervals($date1, $date2));

?>
```

output:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  //...
  ["s"]=>
  int(80)
  //...
}
```